# When accessing a text file on my android device through my PC, part of it doesn't come through

Tags: android

In my android app, I am putting values to a text file and I have confirmed that it works. I can open the text file on my android device and see ALL of the data in there as it should be. However, when I plug the device into my PC via USB, some of the data in the text file gets cut off.

Here's the data I see on my android device when I open the text file:
false,false,false,NULL,NULL,false,false,NULL,NULL,60,67,false,true,1,false,4,1,

Here's the data I see when I access the text file on my computer:
false,false,false,NULL,NULL,false,false,NULL,NULL,60,67,false,true,1,f

As you can see, the last few pieces of data get cut off. I've tried with different data and it still gets cut off there.

I'm not sure if this will help as the following code seemingly does get all the data to the text file (if looking on my android device), but here's the code for writing to the text file. I'm getting two lists of data from SharedPreferences files I've previously created and writing them to a file when a button is pressed.

```
SharedPreferences auto = getSharedPreferences("Auto", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences teleop = getSharedPreferences("Teleop", MODE_PRIVATE);

autoValues = auto.getAll();
teleopValues = teleop.getAll();

public void writeToFile(View view){
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : autoValues.entrySet()){
            stream.write(entry.getValue().toString().getBytes());
            stream.write(",".getBytes());
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : teleopValues.entrySet()){
            stream.write(entry.getValue().toString().getBytes());
            stream.write(",".getBytes());
        }
        stream.close();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS: MAY HAVE WRITTEN TO FILE IN EXPORT");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR: DID NOT WRITE TO FILE");
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to show how you write the file on your Android device. Instead you should show how you read the file on your pc as it is there that you have problems.

Comment: I simply plug in my device and navigate to it using File Explorer on Windows.

Comment: File Explorer on windows does not show you the context of txt files. Use notepad to view the content.

Comment: I'm already opening it with notepad, I'm just saying that I navigate to it using File Explorer. When I open it, it only shows part of the data I see when I open the text file on my android device.

Comment: You also still did not tell how you open the file using Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to efficiently write to your file. **You must have permission to access external storage**.

```
public static void logToFile(String message) {
            String formattedData = String.format("%s", (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
                    .format(new Date())) + "\t\t\t" + message + "\n");

            FileOutputStream stream = null;
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
            try {
                File file = new File(path + "/Logger.txt");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                stream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                stream.write(formattedData.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }`. Remove that code. It does not serve anything and is confusing.

Comment: Didn't work. When accessing the text file on the computer by plugging in my device and navigating to it, it only contains 64 characters (I think, I didn't actually count). I gets cut off after that many for some reason. I can see everything if I look at it on the device which is weird.